# repeated AJAX call with http code return

Tags: php, jquery

When a button is clicked I have a jquery AJAX call such as:

```
$(".play").click(function(){
    function doAjax(){
        $.ajax({
        url: 'blah.php',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data==250)
            {
                setTimeout(doAjax, 2000);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#quote p').html(data);
            }

        }
        });
    }
    doAjax();
});
```

Any data from the server is printed to the div:

```
<div id="quote"><p> </p></div>
```

blah.php on the server does some processing to retrieve some status codes:

```
$r = new HttpRequest('http://localhost...', HttpRequest::METH_GET);
$r->send();

if ($r->getResponseCode() == 200)
{
echo "Starting video..."        
//sends a video to play
}
else if ($r->getResponseCode() == 450)
{
    echo "Oops! Not found...";
}
else if ($r->getResponseCode() == 550)
{
    echo "Oops! An error occurred...";
}
else if ($r->getResponseCode() == 250)
{
    echo "Initializing...";
}
else
{
    echo "Now we are in trouble";
}
```

The response codes (`$r->getResponseCode()`) get returned as I expect, so my problem is with my repeated ajax call with `setTimeout`. What I want to happen is that when code 250 is returned it prints out `Initializing`, which it does, but then my AJAX call will repeat because the success function is called with 250.  This doesn't work. It says `Initializing` but never repeats, because the next step is that I should see `Starting video...`.

Everything else seems to check out, I guess the problem is with my jquery `success` function?

Comment: You say HTTP codes, but you use things like `250` and `550`, which are not valid HTTP status codes. I would advise you use a less misleading term, like simply "status code".

Comment: yes, fair enough it is edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the "data" variable that you have access to in Javascript is actually the exact text that you're echoing in your PHP file, blah.php.

So a more accurate way of making it work is checking if data == "Initializing...". You may also want to consider outputting JSON-compatible text from your PHP file so that you can get both a status code and a message.

Consider putting this as your PHP:

```
$code = $r->getResponseCode();
$message = "";

switch($code) {
    case 200:
        $message = "Starting video...";
        break;
    case 450:
        $message = "Oops! Not found...";
        break;
    case 550:
        $message = "Oops! An error occurred...";
        break;
    case 250:
        $message = "Initializing...";
        break;
    default:
        $message = "Unknown status";
        break;  
}

print "{ 'code': $code, 'message': '$message' }";
```

The above will output all the data you need, in JSON format.

In your javascript, consider using jQuery's built in getJSON method, and parse the data as a regular javascript object.

```
$.getJSON('blah.php', function(data) {
        if (data['code'] == 250)
        {
            setTimeout(doAjax, 2000);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#quote p').html(data['message']);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: I like this solution, but it doesn't work. I get no messages at all. I'll keep debugging.

Comment: Is the problem in your PHP file or in jQuery?

Comment: I think in the jQuery. It never seems to get to the success function. I can put an `alert` in the else and I get nothing.

Comment: You might be getting a server error in the PHP page. Look at it in developer tools, or just request the page to see if it works. I may have typoed my code, if you just copied and pasted it.

Comment: What happens if you console.log() or alert out the data['code'] every time the getJSON function runs?

Comment: Weird, apparently nothing. I don't get any alert and I tried console.log and got nothing in Firebug. Seems to not trigger any success. But in Firebug I can see the JSON code and it has the right values.

Comment: I think this is the right way to go and I believe my problems is in my structure (this being Joomla)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
var timeid = null;

function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'blah.php',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 'Initializing...') {
                time_id = setTimeout(doAjax, 2000);
            } else {
                $('#quote p').html(data);
                if (timeid) {
                    clearTimeout(timeid);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
$(".play").click(doAjax);
```

Comment: how data can be 'Initializing...' , if he return "print "{ 'code': $code, 'message': '$message' }";"

Comment: @voodoo417 Where did you see `he return "print "{ 'code': $code, 'message': '$message' }";"` in the question?

Comment: how you can compare 'data' with string ??

Comment: @voodoo417 Because it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should do it like this, This will work I have tested...

```
$(".play").click(doAjax);

function doAjax(){
   alert(1);
        $.ajax({
        url: 'blah.php',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data==250)
            {
                setTimeout(doAjax, 2000);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#quote p').html(data);
            }

        }
       });   
}
```